# add menu item to the dashboard menu of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, menuitem

I am trying the following syntax to add menu-item on dashboard:

`<?php add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position ); ?>`

But, I am confused where to add this code.

Whether to add it in my theme's functions.php or my plugin's functions.php ?

Or any other way to add custom menu-item on the dashboard of the wordpress logged in as admin ?

I want to add custom menu item like the following image:[image: add_custom_menu_item]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you see in the screenshot is the screen of a [Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types). In the documentation you will find an example code on how to add such a screen.

About where to place the code - it depends. Do you want to be able to use this Custom Post Type in other themes, or you will only need it in this theme?

If you want to use it in other themes as well, put the code in your plugin's code.

If you want to use it only in this theme, put it in your theme's `functions.php`.

And in case you still want to add a custom menu page, [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page#Examples) you will find examples on what is the proper way to use this function. What you should note, is that the call to `add_menu_page()` should be done inside a function that is run on the `admin_menu` action.

Here's an example working code with WP 3.4.2

```
function register_custom_menu_page() {
    add_menu_page('custom menu title', 'custom menu', 'add_users', 'custompage', '_custom_menu_page', null, 6); 
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_custom_menu_page');

function _custom_menu_page(){
   echo "Admin Page Test";  
}
```

Comment: Thank for suggesting an answer, I tried add_menu_page() in my theme's functions.php, but according to wordpress 3.4.2...this function is not working or adding a menu_item to my dashboard..
Is there any new modifications for such function in wordpress 3.4.2 ??
Or i found a file named menu.php in my wp-admin folder, will making changes in this file work ?? If yes, then please tell me, what changes are supposed to be made ??
@Nikola Ivanov Nikolov

Comment: The function is working properly as long as you call it from a function hooked to the `admin_menu` action hook. I've updated my answer with a sample code. You should not modify core files(files located in the root directory, in `/wp-admin` or `/wp-includes` directories). Just add the code from my answer to your theme's functions.php and it should work. If it doesn't then make sure you are editing the proper functions.php(the ones of the currently active theme.

Comment: Please make sure that your call to function "add_action('admin_menu', 'register_custom_menu_page');" is outside the other functions. I lost a couple of hours in a try to call it inside the activation hook function.

Answer (score -2):

This is a perfect answer.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'acme_product',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Products' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
}
```